# CalendarView visibility

Tags: android

How can I hide a `CalenderView` in android app?

Setting `android:visibility = "gone"` is not working.

Here is the code that I have:

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background ="#ffffff"
    android:visibility = "gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    />
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the spaces around the `=`

Comment: Nope. I've tried that and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your calendar view in frame layout and play with its visibility.

```
 <FrameLayout
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:id="@+id/frm"              
 android:layout_width="match_parent"             
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">              

<CalendarView
  android:id="@+id/cal"              
  android:layout_width="match_parent"               
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:calendarViewShown="false"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />   //add this
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Using DatePicker actually does the trick. But I had to use android:visibility="gone" instead of android:calendarViewShown="false".

Comment: try `calenderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in code

Comment: I have both these codes in the datepicker.
    android:visibility = "gone"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" . I've also added to the class calenderView.setVisibility(View.GONE) but still it remains visible

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the cause of the whole problem. I had this piece of code in `onCreate` method:

```
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(this);
setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use **gone** use **invisible** instead

```
<CalendarView
android:id="@+id/calendar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background ="#ffffff"
android:visibility = "invisible"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
/>
```